# JavaScript element.contains returns false for conditionally rendered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a form selector component and I want the dropdown element to close when a user clicks elsewhere on the screen.

The component is designed as follows:

```
export const FormSelect = ({
  defaultText,
  disabled,
  formError,
  formSuccess,
  formWarning,
  groupTitle,
  items,
  isOpen,
  selected,
  selectorId,
  selectorWidth,
  setSelected,
  setIsOpen,
  textCaption,
  textCaptionError,
  textCaptionSuccess,
  textLabel,
}) => {

  const toggling = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const mainSelector = React.useRef(null);

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById("option-container");

    document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      var isClickInsideElement = ignoreClickOnMeElement.contains(event.target);

      if (!isClickInsideElement) {
        closeMenu();
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id={"option-container"}>
      <SelectContainer>
        {isOpen ? (
          <ArrowUp />
        ) : (
          <ArrowDownward />
        )}
      </SelectContainer>
      <div>
        {isOpen ? (
          <OptionContainer>
            <OptionList>
              {groupTitle ? (
              {items.map((item, index) => (
                <ListItem/>
              ))}
            </OptionList>
          </OptionContainer>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>)
```

The useEffect hook contains the logic to close the component if a user clicks outside of the "option-container".  However, the form will not open if a user clicks directly on `ArrowDown`. I am fairly certain this is because the logic checking if the user click is within "option-container" is resulting in `false`.

```
      if (!isClickInsideElement) {
        closeMenu();
      }
```

Why is the conditionally rendered element not considered inside the container around it?

Answer (score -1):

This element:

```
var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById("option-container");
```

is retrieved once, right after the component mounts. But there's no guarantee that that exact element is the same one that exists in the DOM when the click listener runs. If you try logging `ignoreClickOnMeElement.isConnected`, it may give you `false`, indicating that it's not in the DOM anymore.

Retrieve the element only inside the click listener instead - or, even better, use a ref instead of using `getElementById`.

Live demo:

```js
const FormSelect = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById("option-container");
            var isClickInsideElement = ignoreClickOnMeElement.contains(event.target);
            console.log('isClickInsideElement', isClickInsideElement);
        });
    }, []);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState();
    return (
        <div id="option-container">
            option container content
            <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>toggle</button>
            {open ? <div>open</div> : <div>closed</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<FormSelect />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div>
other content outside option container
<div class='react'></div>
other content outside option container
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried using `ref.current` and the same problem is occurring.

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly one element with an ID of `option-container` in the DOM? If you have more than one, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes, exactly one.  It seems like that `option-container` doesn't update as the component conditionally renders.

Comment: Using a ref or retrieving the element inside the handler instead of on pageload should fix it - if not, there's some context missing in the question's code that must be causing the issue too. See the live demo in the question which appears to work as desired.